# Wordpress rewrite_rules_array rule not working properly

Tags: permalinks, woocommerce-offtopic

I want the WooCommerce way to create new rules for permalinks. I have checked WooCommerce core files and found that WooCommerce is using this filter for saving the rule in database. My current url is http://amit.com/wcommerce/seller-login/?page=mpProfile. I have var dumped get_query_var('pagename'); on hit page, but hitting url shows blank. I want this url as http://amit.com/wcommerce/seller-login/mpProfile. Any one have any idea over this part? I have been stuck on this for around 3 days.

Here is my code:

```
    add_action( 'wp_loaded','my_flush_rules' );
    add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array','my_insert_rewrite_rules' );
    add_filter( 'query_vars','my_insert_query_vars' );

    function my_flush_rules() {
        $rules = get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );

            if ( ! isset( $rules['(seller-login)/(.+)$'] ) ) {
                global $wp_rewrite;
                $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
            }

    }

    function my_insert_rewrite_rules( $rules ) { 
        $newrules = array();
        $newrules['(seller-login)/(\d*)$'] = 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]';
        // var_dump($newrules);     
        return $newrules + $rules;
    }

    function my_insert_query_vars( $vars ) {

        array_push($vars, 'pagename');

        return $vars;
    }
```

Comment: when i hit http://amit.com/wcommerce/seller-login/mpProfile i need pagename variable so that i can use this variable right now it is showing page not found

Comment: is seller-login a valid page/slug?

Comment: Yes it is a valid slug actually it is a page

Comment: Possible duplicate, i think it's answered here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/239849/rewrite-rule-never-matching/239852#239852

Answer (score -2, accepted):

things are working by using  rewrite_rules_array filter
    1 :- i want to know the difference between add_rewrite_url() and rewrite_rules_array filter 
    also i want to add array of rules in rewrite_rules_array filter but currently its not working only one of the rule is working others are not 
    thanks

Comment: I got fixed this issue someone nedd help you can comment here